# Hosting mail for domain separately - using Godaddy/Plesk/MediaTemple/Heroku

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

So currently I have a domain name managed through godaddy.

Its hosted on Heroku, and I use custom DNS zones through godaddy, as heroku doesn't host email.

I have a mediatemple account, which I'd like to use to host the email for this domain.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. GoDaddy will have help or contact information to get your MX record pointed correctly.